# How to subscribe to topics using ROS Support from MATLAB?

Tags: ros, matlab, rosmatlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am testing the new [ROS support from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.es/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html).
I have the provided examples working without problems. Actually, the examples show how the subscribers work with messages published by the same matlab node (It also worked for me), but when I try to subscribe the matlab node to a topic from a c++ node, the Matlab code never calls the handle function though I see in rqt_graph the connection established.

You can reproduce this issue by using the basic_example in the previously posted link and changing the topic_name and topic_type in the subscriber definition to subscribe to an "external" node.

Please, does anyone found problems with this new and promising tool?

Thanks in advance.

Àngel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130356/how-to-subscribe-to-topics-using-ros-support-from-matlab?/) by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Angel,
i am dealing with the same problem. Apparently the communication between MATLAB and ROS is unidirectional http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/115513-ros-subscriber-callback-is-not-triggered-when-the-master-is-run-from-ros-hydro
so MATLAB can communicate with ROS, but not the other way around.
i am looking for some solutions, and so far i have found this [https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge) but not sure if it will work,

Let me know if you find a proper solution,
greets,
Jaime

UPDATED: okey i found the solution. There is a difference when you  lauch the roscore from terminal and when you do it from MATLAB. Following the next steps worked for me:

1. edit your .bashrc and add these lines:

export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

2. from terminal : roscore
3. now try again the communication with the subscriber from MATLAB. It should now work.

Greets,
Jaime

---

Originally posted by [jaimerv](https://answers.ros.org/users/11726/jaimerv/) with karma: 96 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's basically a bad setup regarding the IP's. See Mathworks support:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119559-why-is-the-ros-subscriber-callback-in-matlab-not-triggered-when-messages-are-published-from-an-exter

---

Originally posted by [jcgarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/12476/jcgarcia/) with karma: 21 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2